# Sum of limit points

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a$ is a limit point of $(a_n)$ and $b$ a limit point of $(b_n)$. If $c_n=a_n+b_n$. Then we have (LP:=Limit Point):

(i) $a$ is a LP of $(a_n)$ and $b$ a LP of $(b_n) \Rightarrow c=a+b$ is a LP of $(c_n)$.
(ii) $c$ is a LP of $c_n \Rightarrow \exists a$ as a LP of $(a_n)$ and $b$ as a LP of $(b_n)$ with $c=a+b$.

I know that (i) is wrong since i can construct two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ which have LP but $a+b$ is not a LP of $(c_n)$. But what about (ii)?

Does something change when I know that both ($(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$) are bounded?

Comment: What's your counterexample for (i)?

Comment: Do your LP's include $\infty$'s?

Comment: Counterexample for (i): $(a_n)$ takes 1 for all even numbers $n$ and $n$ for all uneven $n$. $(b_n)$ takes 1 for all uneven $n$ and 1 for all even $n$. Both have 1 as LP but 2 is not LP of $(c_n)$

Comment: @TylerDur, isn't it possible to take a neighborhood of $1$ that contains no other points of either sequence?  e.g. $(1/2, 3/2)$

Comment: @OpenBall: no it does not

Comment: @tilper: yes, there are few more examples i think

Comment: @TylerDur never mind, I'm mixing up limit point for set and limit point for sequence.

Answer (score 3):

**(i) [FALSE]**: Consider $a_{n}=\boldsymbol{1}_{\{n\text{ is even}\}}$ and $b_{n}=\boldsymbol{1}_{\{n\text{ is odd}\}}$. $1$ is an LP of both sequences, but $2$ is not an LP of $(c_{n})$, which satisfies $c_{n}=1$ for all $n$.

**(i) when $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are bounded [FALSE]**: Use the same counterexample as above.

**(ii) [FALSE]**: Consider $a_{n}=n(-1)^{n}$ and $b_{n}=n(-1)^{n+1}$. Then, $c_{n}=a_{n}+b_{n}=0$ for all $n$ (and hence $c_{n}\rightarrow0$), but neither $(a_{n})$ nor $(b_{n})$ admit convergent subsequences.

**(ii) when $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are bounded [TRUE]**: Extract a subsequence (by using Bolzano-Weierestrass) $(n_{k})$ such that $a_{n_{k}}\rightarrow a$, $b_{n_{k}}\rightarrow b$, and $c_{n_{k}}\rightarrow c$, (for some $a$ and $b$). Now, what happens if we take limits on both sides of $c_{n_{k}}=a_{n_{k}}+b_{n_{k}}$?

Comment: @sigmabe, proofs that use subsequences don't need to be constructive.  It's enough to simply say "there is a subsequence that..." as long as we can explain why there is such a subsequence.

Comment: I think sigmate is right. I have also problems to understand how do you chose one of the two (a and b).

Comment: Ah I apologize, I thought we were discussing (ii). @TylerDur, your counterexample is correct for (i). Do you understand my proof for (ii) with boundedness?

Comment: @sigmabe: perhaps if I write the argument wholly, it will help. Suppose $(a_{n})$ and $(b_{n})$ are bdd. Extract subsequence $(n_{j})$ with $c_{n_{j}}\rightarrow c$. Extract subsequence $(n_{j_{k}})$ with $a_{n_{j_{k}}}\rightarrow a$ by Bolzano-Weirestrass (BW). Extract
a subsequence $(n_{j_{k_{\ell}}})$ with $b_{n_{j_{k_{\ell}}}}\rightarrow b$ by BW. Summarizing, we have $c_{n_{j_{k_{\ell}}}}\rightarrow c$,
$a_{n_{j_{k_{\ell}}}}\rightarrow a$, and $b_{n_{j_{k_{\ell}}}}\rightarrow b$.

Comment: There are 4 point to prove:
(i) for unbounded and for bounded sequences
(ii) for unbounded and for bounded sequences

(i) for unbounded is clear. What about the other 3? 

@sigmabe: Sorry, can you explain in more detail how you chose b?

Comment: @parsiad: By BW it is clear, that we can "extract" such sequences but why this should imply that $a+b=c$? If I extract $a$ than I have to prove that $c-a=:b$ is a LP for $(b_n)$. But How?

Comment: @parsiad: Ok the argument is clear now. But you should write some more words in the solution I think.

Comment: I dont understand how you are using BW? How can I know that there is a subsequence in $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ convergent to $a$ and $b$. BW says only if the sequence are bounded there is a subsequence with a LP. Isnt it?

Comment: @TylerDur: yes, BW was used for (ii) with boundedness.